# Creating a Java program about leap years

Tags: java

I need to make a program(using BlueJ) that takes in a year and tells the user if it was or wasn't a leap year. The year must be after 1582. Any year divisible by 4 is a leap year, unless it is divisible by 100 but not by 400. That last part is what I am having trouble with.

Here is what i have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IfElseEx2
{
    public static void main(){ Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a year");
    int year = S.nextInt();
    if ((year / 400)= 0) {
        System.out.print("That year was not a leap year");
    }
    else if (year<1582){
        System.out.print ("Please enter a year after 1582");
    }
    else if ((year % 4)==0){
        System.out.println("This year was a leap year");
    }
    else if ((year % 4)!= 0){
        System.out.print("This year was not a leap year");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your last else-if statement should just be an else statement. That and rgettman's answer. Also, and as a heads up, you seem to be dancing between print and println. Finally, there is a significant difference between Java and JavaScript, so tagging the question as both is a tad confusing :)

Comment: You could also cheat hilariously: http://ideone.com/Zp4lbe (I am... 95% sure your instructor would reject that solution, but it does get the job done.)

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
if ((year / 400)= 0) {
```

you need to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.  Try

```
if ((year / 400) == 0) {
```

Additionally, you'll need to cover cases such as the year 1900, divisible by 100 but *not* 400, that aren't leap years.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `GregorianCalendar.isLeapYear` method

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and see if it works . I have just modified your code and added some extra conditions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyTry
{
    public static void main(String[] args){  
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a year");
    int year = S.nextInt();
    if (year > 1582){

    if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)==0)) {
        System.out.print("That year was a leap year");
    }
    else if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)!=0)){
        System.out.println("This year was not a leap year");
    }
    else if ((year%4)== 0){
        System.out.print("This year was a leap year");
    }
    else 
        System.out.print("This year was not a leap year");
    }
    else 
       System.out.print ("Please enter a year after 1582");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A leap year is divided by 4 and not by 100, or divided by 400.

Here is how you can check a Leap year:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Leap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year;
        boolean check;

        // Keep taking entries as long as the
        // inserted value is not valid (less than 1582)
        do {
            System.out.print("Input year (greater than 1582): ");
            year = s.nextInt();
        } while (year < 1582);

        //A Leap year is a year that is divided by 4 and not by 100,
        //or divided by 400.
        check = (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0));

        // Print out the result
        System.out.format("Is year %d a leap year: %b\n", year, check);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Unihedron, true, you can use Ternary operators in this case, but I was going for basic approach. Just comment the Boolean check, and the if..else statements,  and simply replace it with the following print statement: `System.out.format("Is year %d a leap year: %b\n", year, ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0))) ? true: false);`

Comment: True! Sorry did not get your point initially...Still, using a ternary operator can still reduce the code lines by omitting the declaration of the boolean, initializing it and printing it.